# Modify object in base but return pointer to derived class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a kind of object registry where objects can be registered. This should be done in the initialization phase. E.g.

```
class ObjectBase {
protected:
   bool active;

public:
   void activate() { active = true; }
};

template<typename T>
class Object : public ObjectBase {
   T value;
};

class Registry {
public:
   template<typename T>
   static std::shared_ptr<Object<T>> registerObject() {
      return std::make_shared<Object<T>>();
   }

namespace {
   std::shared_ptr< Object<int> > myObject = Registry::registerObject<int>();
}
```

Now I want the `active` value set at initialisation (and constructor parameters are not an option, as **this is but one of many**). What would be neat is if I were able to do the following:

```
namespace {
   std::shared_ptr< Object<int> > myObject = Registry::registerObject<int>()->activate();
}
```

However I don't see a way for activate() to return a pointer of type Object (unless I make it a template as well and do a dynamic cast, however this seems ugly), lest so a shared pointer. Or is there some way? Alternatively, do any of you have a recommendation how to approach this task (i.e. register something and set a number of properties)?

EDIT:

Naming my class `Object` may have been unfortunate. As a practical example, think of Object as a property (holding an integer). Obviously there may be multiple integer properties. And imagine "active" as something akin to "should be backed up" / "should be synced with a remote process" / ...

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't just call `activate()` in `ObjectBase`'s constructor?

Comment: Because I have currently 4 such bool values with more likely to come.

Comment: If that's the case, then more information is needed to properly answer the question. For example, is there a case where you'd *not* want to activate an object when it's constructed?

Comment: That's actually the main case for this variable, only very few objects will (and must) be activated at construction, whereas the majority will be activated later when required. Same for the other variables.

Comment: Right now the design you seem to be aiming for for object initialization seems somewhat contrived. I'm curious to know what these other variables are, as it might give more insight into what you're trying to do with the `Registry` and `Object` relationship.

Comment: Additionally, what does being `active` mean? And why couldn't this be set after the object is registered?

Comment: I've added a quick example in case of any misunderstandings. I can solve this problem differently, but I thought this approach would be prettier, had a feeling it is possible and wanted to ask whether it is and how.

Comment: Are the variables you want to initialize always `bool`, and are they always `false` if *not* activated?

Comment: @Oguk: At the moment they are all bool and false by default. I don't think this is going to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr< Object<T> > RegisterAndActivate() {
  std::shared_ptr< Object<T> > p = Registry::registerObject<T>();
  p->activate();
  return p;
}

namespace {
   std::shared_ptr< Object<int> > myObject = RegisterAndActivate<int>();
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there are currently 4 such bool values with more to come. Having a specific Register-function for every single one of them (and every combination) is something I'd really like to avoid :-)

Comment: Have one Register function taking four boolean variables as parameters (or a bitset, or whatever structure you want to use to represent the desired state of the object).

Comment: And when I have 20 variables? This does not scale.

Comment: One way or another, you would have to describe the desired combination of those 20 variables. Whichever way you choose to do so, have Register function accept that. I suspect you might be looking for a [`Builder` pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

What about freestanding function(s):

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<Object<T>> activate(std::shared_ptr<Object<T>> ptr) {
    ptr->activate();
    return ptr;
}
```

Then

```
auto x = activate(Registry::registerObject<int>());
```

Comment: This may be an option if the other style is not possible, yes.

Comment: @BillP Having that you might get sophisticated, let registerObject return a proxy convertible to 'std::shared_ptr<Object<T>>' and applicable to some comma operators (activate, deactivate, ...) - maybe your design is questionable !?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>


struct Test {
    bool a;
    bool b;
    Test() : a(false),b(false) {};
};


template<typename T, bool T::* ... props>
std::shared_ptr<T> activate(std::shared_ptr<T> inst) {
    std::tie((inst.get()->*props)...) = std::make_tuple((props,true)...);
    return inst;
}

int main()
{
    auto t1 = activate<Test,&Test::a>(std::make_shared<Test>());
    auto t2 = activate<Test,&Test::a,&Test::b>(std::make_shared<Test>());
    std::cout << "t1: a = " << t1->a << ", b = " << t1->b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t2: a = " << t2->a << ", b = " << t2->b << std::endl;
}
```

Basically, whatever pointers to bool members you specify as template parameters, those are going to be set to true by the `activate` function. This way, you don't have to write many activate functions, but it is still a lot of writing because of all the `Classname::classmember` expressions. Working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a7f7a495c6ade3c).